# How to convert follwoing selector of ngRx to boolean return?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

Currently, I use the below filter to return some data list within the given date range. Actually, in the component, I checked only list length and according to that, assing True and False for the variable. I need to know how to convert this directly return boolean and is that way is correct?

```
export const selectModel = (planedDate: Date) => createSelector(
 selectDrugReviews,
 (reviews: ReviewModel[]) => reviews.filter(date => date.startDateTime.getTime() <= planedDate.getTime() && (date.endDateTime !== undefined ? date.endDateTime.getTime() >= planedDate.getTime() : true))
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
export const selectModel = (planedDate: Date) => createSelector(
 selectDrugReviews,
 (reviews: ReviewModel[]) => reviews.map((date) => date.startDateTime.getTime() <= planedDate.getTime() && (date.endDateTime !== undefined ? date.endDateTime.getTime() >= planedDate.getTime() : true))
);
```

Comment: I will try this.. Is it ok to remove the filter also? I try it, it is returned Observable<boolean[]> ?

Comment: can I change this to Observable<boolean> , is there any data available, need to return true?

Comment: @uma I am not sure what you mean, do you want to return Observable or it is returning Observable?

Comment: I mean previously, I used filter and add element only condition true. here not a filter, just a map. is it ok I am just taking [0] from that Boolean[] array ?(or am I need to iterate that array and need to check are there any true values?

Comment: simple ,I need to know , if this return only true values ?

Comment: @uma the array index 0 means you are only taking care of first element of array if that matches it will return true, false otherwise.

Comment: The return is depends upon conditions if they satisfied return true else false.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use  pipe `map` rather then filter.

```
map((date) => <condition here>));
```

Comment: is this way map only - True values ? (I need return just True , if there any one codition- true)

Comment: then filter is ok for you. you can use map and filter together.